Ssh connection failure to Ubuntu virtual machine
I have a windows laptop and have a virtual Ubuntu 24.06 version.I am trying to connect to the ubuntu virtual machine with ssh from the windows host OS.I get an error like "/bin/bash: no file or directory". I did enter the right username and password in putty, selected port 22.The user I used to through ssh is a user i previously used for connecting with SFTP.It is possible to do so,right?I suspect the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh.How to fix this?
I commented the line(in sshd_config) that allows SFTP,and changed the Chroot from /home to /home/sftp_user(username),changed Match group to Match user.

Setting up a chroot for sftp is straightforward (provided you use internal-sftp) because no additional programs or libraries are required. For interactive SSH there's a lot more involved - see for example chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Please check and correct your details; you mention a Ubuntu product released in 2024-June (24.06) where the main Ubuntu products where released in April (thus are 24.04) with Ubuntu Core 24 released in June; which are you asking about.
